# What is a bad selector?

Tags: css-selectors

In the error console concerning a math lab program, there is a continuous error reporting about a bad selector. What is a bad selector?

Comment: Whenever there's an error message, someone in the past has probably already asked about it on the 'net: so you can often get information by using Google to search for the exact error message text (and maybe the name of the product).

Comment: > In the error console concerning a math lab program.

Do you mean Matlab program or is there something called math lab that I"m not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

A selector, generally, is a label / path to a code element.  For example, in CSS, to style any paragraphs within a container div with id="container", the selector is
#container p, where # just means 'id'.  I imagine in other languages it means something similar - the program is looking for an element but can't find the one it's been told to, so it throws the error.